# How do i set a cookie or a header on index.html in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, header, vue.js

I am working on a spring boot application which has vue.js code.

Now on the initial context "/", I would like to set a cookie or a header on the index.html page.

I have tried the following code and i keep getting a 404. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws IOException {

    String reqUrl = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
    String displayName = httpServletRequest.getHeader("displayName");

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(displayName)) {

        String url = "http://example.com/sso/?targetUrl=" + reqUrl;

        URL obj = new URL(url);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        System.out.println("Header from SSO" + con.getHeaderField("displayName"));
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("displayName", con.getHeaderField("displayName"));
    }

    return "index";
}

}
```

This is how my project structure looks like.

[image: Project Structure of Spring Boot App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem i had to change my return statement to

```
return "index.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get a header from the HttpURLConnection you've just created?

If you're trying to relay to the ""http://example.com/sso" url you're better of using httpClient.